# How to catch integer divide by zero and access violation exceptions in native C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I need to catch Integer divide by zero and access violation reading or writing a protected memory and display my own dialog, and do something approprate. These exception can not be catched by try {} catch {} mechanism because hardware generates these exceptions.
How can I catch there exceptions?
Any suggestions or reference to related articles appreciated
mr.abzadeh

Comment: What's your platform? That is OS dependant.

Comment: Windows - see the tag Visual-c++

Comment: My platform is C++ Native(VS2101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange not to have the possibility to catch these exceptions. but if it's like that, than i guess you can put your own validations and throw your own exceptions. But again, you may be missing something...

Comment: I tried this code __try { //divide by zero instruction } __except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)

Answer (score 8):

See the documentation for `__try` / `__except` mechanism.
This is used in Windows for catching hardware exceptions.

Comment: I tried this code __try { //divide by zero instruction } __except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO ? EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH) { //exception routine } and it worked well. I have got the resonse for my question. Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very easy way to catch any kind of exception (division by zero, access violation, etc.) in Visual Studio using **try -> catch (...) block** :)

A minor project tweaking is enough. Just enable /EHa option in project settings. See **Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Modify the Enable C++ Exceptions to "Yes With SEH Exceptions"**. That's it!

See details here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)